# Erroneous HTML tags in toast notification

Tags: bug, voting, html-entities

[image: Image of a toast notification with html tags that shouldn't be there]

I found an error on a Stack Exchange pop-up. Likely whatever is generating the message (js/node etc) is not parsing the HTML text of the pop-up correctly.

Could this be fixed?

Comment: Ah, other people have noticed it too. Is it correct protocol on this site to delete this post?

Comment: You probably shouldn't delete this post, it can redirect people to the other question

Comment: Yep, as MrMythical says, this can serve as a signpost to point people towards the original bug report.